# ubuntu20.04 awk Variable assignment

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I want to get two numbers in two lines

```
awk '/\!/ {E=$5} $1=="PWSCF" {printf"%4d %s %s\n",'$ecut',E,$3}' $name.$ecut.out >> calc-ecut.dat.3
```

and i got the error message

```
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\! ' is not a known regexp operator
```

then this two sentences in # can both realize the function(the actual line about the var E is 
`!    total energy              =     -15.37741390 Ry`)

```
# E=$(cat $name.$ecut.out|grep "!"|sed 's/^.*\=//g'|sed 's/Ry//g'|sed 's/[[:space:]]//g')
# E=$(awk '$1=="!" {printf $5}' $name.$ecut.out)
awk '$1=="PWSCF" {printf"%4d %s %s\n",'$ecut','$E',$3}' $name.$ecut.out >> calc-ecut.dat
```

Comment: I think that you can get access to the environment variables through the use of ENVIRON array, so in order to get access to the var $ecut you'll code `ENVIRON["ecut"}` , also don't escape the bang, as it is  it'll not be interpreted as illegal regexp, neither an error.
However that program will only work when first field is "PWSCF" and it gets contradicted with the "!" since it is the first field.

HTH

Comment: thank you a lot,so do i have any approaches to realize this function in a awk ?the key var is "$3" in "PWSCF" line and "$E" in the "!" line actually

Comment: Avoid a RE using the string test `index ($1, "!")`.

Comment: Jacob, I apologize, but think that I´m not fully understanding what you´re trying to acomplish, looks like you are doing some metaprocessing of the data in order to generate some kind of info that will be used by your program later, I suggest you that you do that inside the AWK program making use of the regExp that allow you to discriminate certain records for an specific treatment.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\!/` should just be `/!/` as `!` is not a regexp metacharacter, it's already literal. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script as you have other issues in that regard, and never do `printf $5`, always `printf "%s", $5` as the former will fail if/when the input contains printf metachars like `%s`. Finally - copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the remaining issues it tells you about.

Comment: Wow, how kind you're, this gives me another useful tool, that I was not aware of; thanks for the aditional insight.